# Create a dataframe from nested xml and generate a csv

Tags: python, xml, csv, dataframe, nested

I have an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PropertySet>
    <PropertySet NumOutputObjects="1" >
        <Message IntObjectName="Class Def" MessageType="Integration Object">
            <ListOf_Class_Def>
                <ImpExp Type="CLASS_DEF" Name="lp_pkg_cla" Object_Num="1001p">
                    <ListOfObject_Def>
                        <Object_Def Ancestor_Num="" Ancestor_Name="">
                        </Object_Def>
                    </ListOfObject_Def>
                    <ListOfObject_Arrt>
                        <Object_Arrt Orig_Id="6666p" Attr_Name="LP_Portable">
                        </Object_Arrt>
                    </ListOfObject_Arrt>
                </ImpExp>
            </ListOf_Class_Def>
        </Message>
    </PropertySet>
    <PropertySet NumOutputObjects="1" >
        <Message IntObjectName="Class Def" MessageType="Integration Object">
            <ListOf_Class_Def>
                <ImpExp Type="CLASS_DEF" Name="M_pkg_cla" Object_Num="1023i">
                    <ListOfObject_Def>
                        <Object_Def Ancestor_Num="" Ancestor_Name="">
                        </Object_Def>
                    </ListOfObject_Def>
                    <ListOfObject_Arrt>
                        <Object_Arrt Orig_Id="7010p" Attr_Name="O_Portable">
                        </Object_Arrt>
                        <Object_Arrt Orig_Id="7012j" Attr_Name="O_wireless">
                        </Object_Arrt>
                    </ListOfObject_Arrt>
                </ImpExp>
            </ListOf_Class_Def>
        </Message>
    </PropertySet>
    <PropertySet NumOutputObjects="1" >
        <Message IntObjectName="Prod Def" MessageType="Integration Object">
            <ListOf_Prod_Def>
                <ImpExp Type="PROD_DEF" Name="Laptop" Object_Num="2008a">
                    <ListOfObject_Def>
                        <Object_Def Ancestor_Num="1001p" Ancestor_Name="lp_pkg_cla">
                        </Object_Def>
                    </ListOfObject_Def>
                    <ListOfObject_Arrt>
                    </ListOfObject_Arrt>
                </ImpExp>
            </ListOf_Prod_Def>
        </Message>
    </PropertySet>
    <PropertySet NumOutputObjects="1" >
        <Message IntObjectName="Prod Def" MessageType="Integration Object">
            <ListOf_Prod_Def>
                <ImpExp Type="PROD_DEF" Name="Mouse" Object_Num="2987d">
                    <ListOfObject_Def>
                        <Object_Def Ancestor_Num="1023i" Ancestor_Name="M_pkg_cla">
                        </Object_Def>
                    </ListOfObject_Def>
                    <ListOfObject_Arrt>
                    </ListOfObject_Arrt>
                </ImpExp>
            </ListOf_Prod_Def>
        </Message>
    </PropertySet>
    <PropertySet NumOutputObjects="1" >
        <Message IntObjectName="Prod Def" MessageType="Integration Object">
            <ListOf_Prod_Def>
                <ImpExp Type="PROD_DEF" Name="Speaker" Object_Num="5463g">
                    <ListOfObject_Def>
                        <Object_Def Ancestor_Num="" Ancestor_Name="">
                        </Object_Def>
                    </ListOfObject_Def>
                    <ListOfObject_Arrt>
                    </ListOfObject_Arrt>
                </ImpExp>
            </ListOf_Prod_Def>
        </Message>
    </PropertySet>
</PropertySet>
```

I am hoping to extract the `Name`, `Object_Num`, `Orig_Id` and `Attr_Name` tags from it using Python and convert them into a .csv format.

The .csv format I'd like to see it in is simply:

```
ProductId   Product AttributeId Attribute
2008a   Laptop  6666p           LP_Portable
2987d   Mouse   7010p           O_Portable
2987d   Mouse   7012p           O_Wireless
5463g   Speaker ""          ""
```

Actually there is a relationship like this in xml tags:

1. All products are in the tags, "ImpExp Type="PROD_DEF".. "
2. All attributes are in the tags, "ImpExp Type="CLASS_DEF".. "
3. If a product has attributes, then there is a tag
   `<Object_Def Ancestor_Num="1023i".. >`
4. The `Ancestor_Num` is equal to `Object_Num` in tags, 
   `Type="CLASS_DEF"..`

I have tried this:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas
import HTMLParser 

inFile = "./newm.xml"
outFile = "./new.csv"

ctx1 = etree.iterparse(inFile, tag=("ImpExp", "ListOfObject_Def", "ListOfObject_Arrt",))


hp = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
csvData = []
csvData1 = []
csvData2 = []
csvData3 = []
csvData4 = []
csvData5 = []

for event, elem in ctx1:
    value1 = elem.get("Type")
    value2 = elem.get("Name")
    value3 = elem.get("Object_Num")
    value4 = elem.get("Ancestor_Num")
    value5 = elem.get("Orig_Id")
    value6 = elem.get("Attr_Name")
    if value1 == "PROD_DEF":
        csvData.append(value2)
        csvData1.append(value3)
        for event, elem in ctx1:
            if value4 is not None:
                csvData2.append(value4)
                elem.clear()

df = pandas.DataFrame({'Product':csvData, 'ProductId':csvData1, 'AncestorId':csvData2})

for event, elem in ctx1: 
    if value1 == "Class Def":
        csvData3.append(value3)
        csvData4.append(value5)
        csvData5.append(value6)
        elem.clear()

df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'AncestorId':csvData3, 'AttribId':csvData4, 'AttribName':csvData5})

dff = pandas.merge(df, df1, on="AncestorId")
dff.to_csv(outFile, index = False)
```

Comment: You've shown what you have tried, but you need to edit the question to include what and where the problems are that you are having.

Comment: The problem is , using this code I can't get that table as a output. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files and can directly convert XML to CSV (i.e., text file) without the pandas dataframe intermediary. Python's third-party module `lxml` (which you are already using) can run XSLT 1.0 scripts and do so without `for` loops or `if` logic. However, due to the complex alignment of product and attributes, some longer XPath searches are used with XSLT.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="no" method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="delimiter">,</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/PropertySet">
      <xsl:text>ProductId,Product,AttributeId,Attribute&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PropertySet|Message|ListOf_Class_Def|ListOf_Prod_Def|ImpExp">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ListOfObject_Arrt">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Object_Arrt"/>
    <xsl:if test="name(*) != 'Object_Arrt' and preceding-sibling::ListOfObject_Def/Object_Def/@Ancestor_Name = ''">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::ImpExp/@Name, $delimiter,
                                    ancestor::ImpExp/@Object_Num, $delimiter,
                                    '', $delimiter,
                                    '')"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>   
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Object_Arrt">
    <xsl:variable name="attrName" select="ancestor::ImpExp/@Name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(/PropertySet/PropertySet/Message[@IntObjectName='Prod Def']/ListOf_Prod_Def/
                                 ImpExp[ListOfObject_Def/Object_Def/@Ancestor_Name = $attrName]/@Name, $delimiter,

                                 /PropertySet/PropertySet/Message[@IntObjectName='Prod Def']/ListOf_Prod_Def/
                                 ImpExp[ListOfObject_Def/Object_Def/@Ancestor_Name = $attrName]/@Object_Num, $delimiter,

                                 @Orig_Id, $delimiter,
                                 @Attr_Name)"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL
xml = et.parse('Input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('XSLT_Script.xsl')

# RUN TRANSFORMATION
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)    
result = transform(xml)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
with open('Output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

**Output**

```
ProductId,Product,AttributeId,Attribute
Laptop,2008a,6666p,LP_Portable
Mouse,2987d,7010p,O_Portable
Mouse,2987d,7012j,O_wireless
Speaker,5463g,,
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution, thank you soo much for taking the time to explain it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to preparse all of the `CLASS_DEF` entries into a dictionary. These can then be looked up when processing the `PROD_DEF` entries:

```
import csv
from lxml import etree

inFile = "./newm.xml"
outFile = "./new.csv"

tree = etree.parse(inFile)
class_defs = {}

# First extract all the CLASS_DEF entries into a dictionary
for impexp in tree.iter("ImpExp"):
    name = impexp.get('Name')

    if impexp.get('Type') == "CLASS_DEF":
        for list_of_object_arrt in impexp.findall('ListOfObject_Arrt'):
            class_defs[name] = [(obj.get('Orig_Id'), obj.get('Attr_Name')) for obj in list_of_object_arrt]

with open(outFile, 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['ProductId', 'Product', 'AttributeId', 'Attribute'])

    for impexp in tree.iter("ImpExp"):
        object_num = impexp.get('Object_Num')
        name = impexp.get('Name')

        if impexp.get('Type') == "PROD_DEF":
            for list_of_object_def in impexp.findall('ListOfObject_Def'):
                for obj in list_of_object_def:
                    ancestor_num = obj.get('Ancestor_Num')
                    ancestor_name = obj.get('Ancestor_Name')

            csv_output.writerow([object_num, name] + list(class_defs.get(ancestor_name, [['', '']])[0]))
```

This would produce `new.csv` containing:

```
ProductId,Product,AttributeId,Attribute
2008a,Laptop,6666p,LP_Portable
2987d,Mouse,7010p,O_Portable
5463g,Speaker,,
```

If you are using Python 3.x, use:

```
with open(outFile, 'w', newline='') as f_output:
```

Comment: This is a also a cleaner solution, but output is much different than I wished. But this is helpful to me to understand about reading nested xml file and extract data.  Thank you so much for taking the time to explain it. :)